# SQL Highest Value for each Type

Tags: sql, oracle, max, distinct

Lets say this is my employee table: employee (id, name, job, sal). Job could be "accountant", "manager", "clerk" etc.. I'm trying to use a sub query to get the highest salary per job type, something like this output:

```
JOB         NAME     SALARY
clerk       Bob      120
accountant  Mike     320
manager     Sam      660
```

SQL I tried:

```
SELECT 
  job, 
  ename, 
  sal 
FROM 
  emp 
WHERE 
 sal = (SELECT MAX(sal) FROM emp where job IN (SELECT DISTINCT(job) FROM emp));
```

I've been trying with the DISTINCT and MAX functions but I'm stuck and can get no where near,  any help please?

Comment: What SQL have you tried?

Comment: SELECT job, ename, sal
FROM emp
WHERE sal = (SELECT MAX(sal) FROM emp where job IN (SELECT DISTINCT(job) FROM emp));

Comment: That should be in your question. Also, try to keep the result formatting. Your original results are hard to read.

Comment: Simple group by JOB with max aggregate of salary is the answer

Comment: Ok I'm still very confused, maybe if I put it this way. I want to find the highest salary value of every row with matching job values.

Comment: Add expected OUTPUT in the question. That will make things better!!

Answer (score 4):

If you just need  max salary per JOB then this should work.

```
SELECT Max(SALARY) AS maxsalary,
       JOB
FROM   employee
GROUP  BY JOB
```

If you need who is getting the max salary per JOB then try this.

```
SELECT t1.JOB,
       t1.NAME,
       t1.SALARY
FROM   employee t1
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Max(SALARY) AS maxsalary,
                          JOB
                   FROM   employee
                   GROUP  BY JOB) t2
               ON t1.JOB = t2.JOB
                  AND t1.SALARY = t2.maxsalary
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured out an answer that looks a bit simpler that the above:

```
SELECT job, name, salary
FROM employee
WHERE (salary, job) IN (SELECT MAX(salary), job FROM employee GROUP BY job);
```

Thanks for the help though